# Codeigniter -> getting 404 error. Simple routes not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am an asp.net guy and this is the first time I've dealt with PHP.

Anyhow, I've struggled to migrate an existing site to a new server.

This site is using codeigniter.

When I call http://mydomain/admin
I get a 404 error!

But if I call:

http://mydomain/index.php/admin

it works!

I have placed an .htaccess file on the root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I have set in the config.php:

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

My routes.php:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = '';
```

I have no idea why it does not work. It must be something very simple I guess...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you getting the CI 404 or the server's 404?

Comment: How would I know if it's CI's error or the server?
It seems to be Apache, since I don't see anything special about it. Here is the link: http://72.9.251.2/~stnoa/admin
maybe you can tell what is wrong.
This one works:
http://72.9.251.2/~stnoa/index.php/admin
Thanks!!!!

Comment: Wait.  The link works now.  Does that mean you have fixed it?....and without reporting back?  For shame! ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you look through this?:
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/

If not, try this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

There used to be one from Jamie Rumbelow I used to use a bit, but it's not on his blog anymore... I'm used to nginx now though, so my favorite configuration won't work for you.

Comment: Matthew,
i have just replaced the contents of .htaccess with what you have pasted and I now get:
500 Internal Server Error
The request was not completed. The server met an unexpected condition.
when calling the page.

Comment: Is there a way to know if mod_rewrite is enabled?

Comment: I'm guessing that the last part of that htaccess say if the module doesn't exist then do a 404 - not sure though. It seems like most of the time (in my experience) it's not enabled by default, but is installed.

Comment: Matthew,
the 500 server error was due end of line encoding.
I used notepad and now the 500 error is gone, but I am again with the 404 error.
Unfortunately it did not help.

Answer (score 2):

Your .htaccess file didn't work for me either.  But it worked once I changed the rewrite rule to this :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I just removed the slash at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

**1º** - Create an .htaccess file in the root you're CodeIgniter project.

**2º** - In the created .htaccess file put the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding  `RewriteBase /` in .htaccess

Comment: you should really check out apache logs for hints about what's going on. Everything seems fine in .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

```
            $default_controller = "home";
            $language_alias = array('gr','fr');
            $controller_exceptions = array('signup');
            $route['default_controller'] = $default_controller;
            $route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")/(".implode('|', $controller_exceptions).")(.*)"] = '$2';
            $route["^(".implode('|', $language_alias).")?/(.*)"] = $default_controller.'/$2';
            $route["^((?!\b".implode('\b|\b', $controller_exceptions)."\b).*)$"] = $default_controller.'/$1';
            foreach($language_alias as $language)
            $route[$language] = $default_controller.'/index';
            $route['404_override'] = '';
```